# Pseudorandom function outputting a field element VS pseudorandom function outputting a string

Tags: block-cipher, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

Assume we have two pseudorandom functions $PRF$ and $PRF'$ defined as follows:

$PRF: \{0,1\}^{n}\times \{0,1\}^{m}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n}$

$PRF': \{0,1\}^{n}\times \{0,1\}^{m}\rightarrow \mathtt{F}_p$

where $p$ is a large prime number, $|p|=l$, and $l$, $n$ are security parameters.

---

**Question** 1: Is $PRF'$ secure and does it meet the standard definition of pseudorandom function?

if yes, then

**Question** 2: Are these two pseudorandom functions are different in terms of the level of security and the probability that collision occurs?

Comment: I'm semi-sure the definition of a PRF is independent of the actual sets. As such the answer to Q1 would be "yes" and the answer to Q2 would be "$\sqrt{p}$ vs n/2"

Comment: What's the standard definition?

Comment: @fkraiem I meant the definition provided in the crypto. textbooks, e.g. introduction to modern cryptography or foundation of cryptography.

Comment: Well then, what is this definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_p$ has a one to one mapping with the set of integers $[0, p)$. $\{0, 1\}^n$ has a one to one mapping with the set of integers $[0, 2^n)$. Their sizes are respectively $p$ and $2^n$.

Both $F_p$ and $\{0, 1\}^n$ are common 
(co)domains chosen due to nice properties in either efficiency, easy analysis or ease of use *in the greater scheme of things*. But to analyse a PRF these are fundamentally the same.

You are mapping one set to another. This mapping must be indistinguishable from a random oracle, within security bounds. For the analysis the only fundamental property are the *sizes and distributions of the sets you're mapping*, not what those sets actually contain.

The birthday attack on secure PRFs roughly dictates that you'll find a collision after $\sqrt{s}$ random outputs, where $s$ is the size of the codomain. So for your question respectively $\sqrt{p}$ and $2^{n/2}$.